# Differentiating a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Knowing that $$z(x,y)=f(\frac{x}{y})$$I'm supposed to find $$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$ .

This problem makes no sense to me, can anyone help with the differentiation ? I really don't get how to apply the chain rule this time .

Comment: Note that $z=f\circ g$, where $g(x,y)=\dfrac x y$ and use the formula for the chain rule which you should have on your notes.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{y}f'(x/y)$$

and

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = -\frac{x}{y^2}f'(x/y)$$

by the chain rule. All together:

$$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial z} = \left(\frac{x}{y} - \frac{x}{y}\right)f'(x/y) = 0$$